# Time out an R command via something like try()

Tags: r

I'm running a large number of iterations in parallel. Certain iterates take much (say 100x) longer than others. I want to time these out, but I'd rather not have to dig into the C code behind the function (call it fun.c) doing the heavy lifting. I am hoping there is something similar to try() but with a time.out option. Then I could do something like:

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
    try(fun.c(args),time.out=60))->to.return[i]
}
```

So if fun.c took longer than 60 seconds for a certain iterate, then the revamped try() function would just kill it and return a warning or something along those lines.

Anybody have any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some nice answers below.  Also look at `?setTimeLimit` in base R.

Comment: Example of @Andrie comment in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908943/170352

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903497/how-does-settimelimit-work-in-r

Answer (score 36):

See this thread: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Time-out-for-a-R-Function-td3075686.html

and `?evalWithTimeout` in the `R.utils` package.

Here's an example:

```
require(R.utils)

## function that can take a long time
fn1 <- function(x)
{
    for (i in 1:x^x)
    {
        rep(x, 1000)
    }
    return("finished")
}

## test timeout
evalWithTimeout(fn1(3), timeout = 1, onTimeout = "error") # should be fine
evalWithTimeout(fn1(8), timeout = 1, onTimeout = "error") # should timeout
```

Comment: This seems perfect, but my initial experimentation with evalWithTimeout() makes me think it doesn't play well at all with the C code. It seems to be greatly lengthening the run time for the iterations that are ok.

Comment: @Ben Ah, that is too bad.  I am not familiar with the inner workings of `evalWithTimeout()`. Perhaps you can try asking the package's author, Henrik Bengtsson (website: http://www.braju.com/R/), for any tips on speeding things up.

Comment: Thanks for recommending the package. Works great. However, fyi, it says: `'evalWithTimeout' is defunct.
Use 'R.utils::withTimeout()' instead.`

Answer (score 16):

This sounds like it should be something that should be managed by whatever is doling out tasks to the workers, rather than something that should be contained in a worker thread.  The `multicore` package supports timeouts for some functions; `snow` doesn't, as far as I can tell.

EDIT: If you're really desperate to have this in the worker threads, then try this function, inspired by the links in @jthetzel's answer.

```
try_with_time_limit <- function(expr, cpu = Inf, elapsed = Inf)
{
  y <- try({setTimeLimit(cpu, elapsed); expr}, silent = TRUE) 
  if(inherits(y, "try-error")) NULL else y 
}

try_with_time_limit(sqrt(1:10), 1)                   #value returns as normal
try_with_time_limit(for(i in 1:1e7) sqrt(1:10), 1)   #returns NULL
```

You'll perhaps want to customise the behaviour in the event of a timeout.  At the moment it just returns `NULL`.

Comment: Excellent point. I hadn't thought to check the worker managers. Unfortunately I'm parallel-izing over multiple nodes so I don't think multicore will work. I'm currently using snow. Drat.

Answer (score 12):

I like `R.utils::withTimeout()`, but I also aspire to avoid package dependencies if I can. Here is a solution in base R. Please note the `on.exit()` call. It makes sure to remove the time limit even if your expression throws an error.

```
with_timeout <- function(expr, cpu, elapsed){
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  envir <- parent.frame()
  setTimeLimit(cpu = cpu, elapsed = elapsed, transient = TRUE)
  on.exit(setTimeLimit(cpu = Inf, elapsed = Inf, transient = FALSE))
  eval(expr, envir = envir)
}
```

Comment: Gotta say, Will, that I'm using this in some "production" shiny apps (tightly coupled with `tryCatch`, of course), nice to be able to limit run-time of some function calls. Thanks for this!

Comment: IIUC `transient=TRUE` isn't necessary for the first call? And we can just do `setTimeLimit()` and rely on defaults to reset? Just want to be sure I'm not missing any subtlety in the answer / learned experience, especially for `transient=` whose explanation in `?setTimeLimit` is not very clear.

Answer (score 9):

You mentioned in a comment that your problem is with C code running long.  In my experience, none of the purely R based timeout solutions based on `setTimeLimit`/`evalWithTimeout` can stop the execution of C code unless the code provides an opportunity to interrupt to R.

You also mentioned in a comment that you are parallelizing over SNOW.  If the machines you are parallelizing to are an OS that supports forking (i.e., not Windows), then you can use mcparallel (in the `parallel` package, derived from `multicore`) within the context of a command to a node on a SNOW cluster; the inverse is also true BTW, you can trigger SNOW clusters from the context of a `multicore` fork.  This answer also (of course) holds if you aren't parallelizing via SNOW, provided the machine that needs to timeout the C code can fork.

This lends itself to `eval_fork`, a solution used by [opencpu](http://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu).  Look below the body of the `eval_fork` function for an outline of a hack in Windows and a poorly implemented half version of that hack.

```
eval_fork <- function(..., timeout=60){

  #this limit must always be higher than the timeout on the fork!
  setTimeLimit(timeout+5);      

  #dispatch based on method
  ##NOTE!!!!! Due to a bug in mcparallel, we cannot use silent=TRUE for now.
  myfork <- parallel::mcparallel({
    eval(...)
  }, silent=FALSE);

  #wait max n seconds for a result.
  myresult <- parallel::mccollect(myfork, wait=FALSE, timeout=timeout);

  #try to avoid bug/race condition where mccollect returns null without waiting full timeout.
  #see https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu/issues/131
  #waits for max another 2 seconds if proc looks dead 
  while(is.null(myresult) && totaltime < timeout && totaltime < 2) {
     Sys.sleep(.1)
     enddtime <- Sys.time();
     totaltime <- as.numeric(enddtime - starttime, units="secs")
     myresult <- parallel::mccollect(myfork, wait = FALSE, timeout = timeout);
  }

  #kill fork after collect has returned
  tools::pskill(myfork$pid, tools::SIGKILL);    
  tools::pskill(-1 * myfork$pid, tools::SIGKILL);  

  #clean up:
  parallel::mccollect(myfork, wait=FALSE);

  #timeout?
  if(is.null(myresult)){
    stop("R call did not return within ", timeout, " seconds. Terminating process.", call.=FALSE);      
  }

  #move this to distinguish between timeout and NULL returns
  myresult <- myresult[[1]];

  #reset timer
  setTimeLimit();     

  #forks don't throw errors themselves
  if(inherits(myresult,"try-error")){
    #stop(myresult, call.=FALSE);
    stop(attr(myresult, "condition"));
  }

  #send the buffered response
  return(myresult);  
}
```

Windows hack:
In principle, especially with worker nodes in SNOW, you could accomplish something similar by having the worker nodes:

1. create a variable to store a temporary file
2. store their workspace (`save.image`) to a known location
3. Use a system call to load `Rscript` with an R script that loads the workspace saved by the node and then saves a result (essentially doing a slow memory fork of the R workspace).
4. Enter a repeat loop on each worker node looking for the result file, if the result file doesn't manifest after your set period of time, break from the loop and save a return value reflecting the timeout
5. Otherwise, successfully complete the look and read the saved the result and have it ready for return

I wrote some code a /long/ time ago for something like mcparallel on Windows on localhost using slow memory copies.  I would write it completely differently now, but it might give you a place to start, so I'm providing it anyway.  Some gotchas to note, `russmisc` was a package I'm writing which now is on github as `repsych`.  `glibrary` is a function in `repsych` that installs a package if it isn't already available (potentially important if your SNOW isn't just on localhost).  ... and of course I haven't used this code for /years/, and I haven't tested it recently - it is possible the version I'm sharing contains errors that I resolved in later versions.

```
# Farm has been banished here because it likely violates 
# CRAN's rules in regards to where it saves files and is very
# windows specific.  Also, the darn thing is buggy.

#' Create a farm
#'
#' A farm is an external self-terminating instance of R to solve a time consuming problem in R.  
#' Think of it as a (very) poor-person's multi-core.
#' For a usage example, see checkFarm.
#' Known issues:  May have a problem if the library gdata has been loaded.//
#' If a farm produces warnings or errors you won't see them
#' If a farm produces an error... it never will produce a result.
#'
#' @export
#' @param commands A text string of commands including line breaks to run.  
#' This must include the result being saved in the object farmName in the file farmResult (both are variables provided by farm() to the farm).
#' @param farmName This is the name of the farm, used for creating and destroying filenames.  One is randomly assigned that is plausibly unique.
#' @param Rloc The location of R.exe.  The default loads the version of R that is stored in the windows registry as being \"current\".
#' @return The farm name is returned to be stored in an object and then used in checkFarm()
#' @seealso \code{\link{checkFarm}} \code{\link{waitForFarm}}
farm <- function(commands,farmName=paste("farm-",as.integer(Sys.time())+runif(1),sep=""),Rloc = NULL)
{
  if (is.null(Rloc)) {Rloc <- paste('\"',readRegistry(paste("Software\\R-core\\R\\",readRegistry("Software\\R-core\\R\\",maxdepth=100)$`Current Version`,"\\",sep=""))$InstallPath,"\\bin",sep="")}
  Rloc <- paste(Rloc,"\\R.exe\"",sep="")
  farmRda <- paste(farmName,".Rda",sep="")
    farmRda.int <- paste(farmName,".int.Rda",sep="") #internal .Rda
    farmR <- paste(farmName,".R",sep="")
    farmResult <- paste(farmName,".res.Rda",sep="") #result .Rda
    unlink(c(farmRda,farmR,farmResult,farmRda.int))
    farmwd <- getwd()
    cat("setwd(\"",farmwd,"\")\n",file=farmR,append=TRUE,sep="")
    #loading the internals to get them, then loading the globals, then reloading the internals to make sure they have haven't been overwritten
  cat("
load(\"",farmRda.int,"\")
load(farmRda)
load(\"",farmRda.int,"\")
        ",file=farmR,append=TRUE,sep="")
    cat("library(russmisc)\n",file=farmR,append=TRUE)
    cat("glibrary(",paste(c(names(sessionInfo()$loadedOnly),names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs)),collapse=","),")\n",file=farmR,append=TRUE)
    cat(commands,file=farmR,append=TRUE)
    cat("
        unlink(farmRda)
        unlink(farmRda.int)
    ",file=farmR,append=TRUE,sep="")
    save(list = ls(all.names=TRUE,envir=.GlobalEnv), file = farmRda,envir=.GlobalEnv)
    save(list = ls(all.names=TRUE), file = farmRda.int)
    #have to drop the escaped quotes for file.exists to find the file
  if (file.exists(gsub('\"','',Rloc))) {
        cmd <- paste(Rloc," --file=",getwd(),"/",farmR,sep="")
    } else {
        stop(paste("Error in russmisc:farm: Unable to find R.exe at",Rloc))
    }
    print(cmd)
    shell(cmd,wait=FALSE)
    return(farmName)
}
NULL

#' Check a farm
#'
#' See farm() for details on farms.  This function checks for a file based on the farmName parameter called farmName.res.Rda.
#' If that file exists it loads it and returns the object stored by the farm in the object farmName.  If that file does not exist,
#' then the farm is not done processing, and a warning and NULL are returned.  Note that a rapid loop through checkFarm() without Sys.sleep produced an error during development.
#'
#' @export
#' @param farmName This is the name of the farm, used for creating and destroying filenames.  This should be saved from when the farm() is created
#' @seealso \code{\link{farm}} \code{\link{waitForFarm}}
#' @examples 
#' #Example not run
#' #.tmp <- "This is a test of farm()"
#' #exampleFarm <- farm("
#' #print(.tmp)
#' #helloFarm <- 10+2
#' #farmName <- helloFarm
#' #save(farmName,file=farmResult)
#' #")
#' #example.result <- checkFarm(exampleFarm)
#' #while (is.null(example.result)) {
#' #    example.result <- checkFarm(exampleFarm)
#' #    Sys.sleep(1)
#' #}
#' #print(example.result)
checkFarm <- function(farmName) {
  farmResult <- paste(farmName,".res.Rda",sep="")
  farmR <- paste(farmName,".r",sep="")
  if (!file.exists(farmR)) {
    message(paste("Warning in russmisc:checkFarm:  There is no evidence that the farm '",farmName,"' exists (no .r file found).\n",sep=""))
  }
    if (file.exists(farmResult)) {
        load(farmResult)
    unlink(farmResult) #delete the farmResult file
    unlink(farmR)      #delete the script file
        return(farmName)
    } else {
        warning(paste("Warning in russmisc:checkFarm:  The farm '",farmName,"' is not ready.\n",sep=""))
        return(invisible(NULL))
    }
}
NULL

#' Wait for a farm result
#'
#' This function repeatedly checks for a farm, when the farm is found it returns the harvest (the farm result object).
#' If the farm terminated with an error or there is some other sort of coding error, waitForFarm will be an infinate loop. As
#' \code{checkFarm} produces errors on checks when the harvest is not ready, waitForFarm hides these errors in the factory error-catching wrapper.
#'
#' @export
#' @param farmName This is the name of the farm, used for creating and destroying filenames.  This should be saved from when the farm() is created
#' @param noCheck If this value is TRUE the check for the farm's .r is skipped.  If it is FALSE, the existance of the appropriate .r is checked for before entering a potentially unending while loop.
waitForFarm <- function(farmName,noCheck=FALSE) {
  f.checkFarm <- factory(checkFarm)
  farmR <- paste(farmName,".r",sep="")
  if (!file.exists(farmR) & !noCheck) {
    stop(paste("Error in russmisc:checkFarm:  There is no evidence that the farm '",farmName,"' exists (no .r file found).\n",sep=""))
  }
  repeat {
    harvest <- f.checkFarm(farmName)
    if (!is.null(harvest[[1]])) {break}
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
    return(harvest[[1]])
}
NULL

#' Create a one-line simple farm
#'
#' This is a convience wrapper function that uses farm to create a single farm appropriate for processing single line commands.
#'
#' @export
#' @param command A single command
#' @param farmName This is the name of the farm, used for creating and destroying filenames.  One is randomly assigned that is plausibly unique.
#' @param Rloc The location of R.exe.  The default loads the version of R that is stored in the windows registry as being \"current\".
#' @return The farm name is returned to be stored in an object and then used in checkFarm()
#' @seealso \code{\link{farm}}, \code{\link{checkFarm}}, and \code{\link{waitForFarm}}
#' @examples
#' #Example not run
#' #a <- 5
#' #b <- 10
#' #farmID <- simpleFarm("a + b")
#' #waitForFarm(farmID)
simpleFarm <- function(command,farmName=paste("farm-",as.integer(Sys.time())+runif(1),sep=""),Rloc = NULL) {
  return(farm(paste("farmName <- (",command,");save(farmName,file=farmResult)",collapse=""),farmName=paste("farm-",as.integer(Sys.time())+runif(1),sep=""),Rloc = NULL))
}
NULL
```

Comment: I like your mcparallel solution. Are the calls to setTimeLimit() strictly necessary? i.e. is there a specific case when the timeout on mccollect will fail? @rpierce

Comment: I'm not the original author of that code, the opencpu folks are (http://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu).  As far as I can tell in practice they shouldn't be strictly necessary - all of the R code that might be terminated by them is quick acting and/or calls out to external code.  I think it might just be there out of an abundance of caution.

Comment: thanks. Will strip it out of my version (hate unnecessary belt and braces) and report back if I ever hit a problem!

Comment: Honorable mention to @FranzB for pointing out a bug guard posted by the OpenCPU folks that I've now incorporated into my answer.

Comment: Shouldn't totaltime  be initalized?

Comment: Man, it's been ages since I wrote that.  This whole approach is probably a horrible idea these days.  Quickly looking back, I don't think you need to initialize `totaltime` because `is.null(myresult)` will be TRUE on the first cycle and the atomic && will guard against the evaluation of totaltime until the loop has gone through once and set that value.

Comment: Actually, for a process that calls to a DB, I have not yet found a better type of approach.

Comment: @DiogoSantos it is horrifying that we've not found a better way on this by 2021... how about now in 2023?

Comment: @russellpierce in 2021 I used this solution for my DB calling process. Since then I abandoned R and started using python :D