# How does setTimeLimit work in R?

Tags: r, timer

I am trying to master `setTimeLimit()` in R and my experience has led to several related questions, so maybe the fundamental question is: how does this really work?  (I have been looking at `evalWithTimeout()` from `R.utils` as well, and it may suit my purposes slightly better, but it's built on this function.)

Here are the key things I am trying to figure out:

1. How does it monitor the elapsed time?  I.e. it seems to get inserted into the flow control, so how does it do that?  Being able to have "background" processes is cool, and could be used for reporting status, checkpointing, and more.
2. Can I determine how much time remains until it is triggered?  I realize I can wrap it and store, somewhere, the elapsed & CPU time consumed at about the point of invocation (i.e. the output of `proc.time()`).  But, this function is already storing these somewhere and I'd like to know where, or at least how to determine the time remaining.
3. Can it be made to do something useful if the R console is idle?  Being able to monitor `elapsed.time()` and `cpu.time()` is very useful.  I'd like to be able to monitor when R is idle, but it seems from tinkering that it requires a command to be submitted or completed.  Moreover, just outputting an error doesn't trigger a subsequent action.  (Maybe I need to give more attention to `evalWithTimeout`.)
4. The help information says that it can be applicable with C or Fortran, but doesn't give examples.  Any suggestions on how this should be done?

Comment: How much experience do you have with multithreaded programming?  As I recall, this simply hooks into a callback mechanism, and thusly gets woken up every couple of processing cycles.  There are examples to use this e.g. to update the prompt of your R terminal session with the current time---which is a silly example per se but a useful illustration nevertheless.

Comment: I can work with multithreaded programming.  I assumed it was a callback, but hadn't tried to pin that down.  What's interesting is it doesn't appear to show up under `getTaskCallbackNames()` or `taskCallbackManager()`.

Answer (score 7):

To show that setTimeLimit does not work during a C function call:

```
rfunction <- function(){
    repeat{
        x <- rnorm(100);
    }
}

cfunction <- function(){
    x <- eigen(matrix(rnorm(1e6), 1e3));
}

setTimeLimit(3);
system.time(try(rfunction(), silent=TRUE))
system.time(try(cfunction(), silent=TRUE))
```