# benchmarking: set maximum number of runtime

Tags: r, benchmarking

is there a way to set a maximum time to evaluate the runtime of an expression via one of the common R-benchmarking packages (e.g. `rbenchmark`, `microbenchmark`, or `bench`)? I am comparing two implementations of an algorithm, where one runs in seconds but the other takes multiple minutes - if possible, I would like to cap the "maximum" runtime used in the "slower" algorithm to a specific time. The overall purpose of the benchmark is less to get exact timing benchmarks for the two algorithms but to demonstrate that one is orders of magnitudes faster.

Comment: I don't think the benchmarking tools do it natively, but https://stackoverflow.com/q/31462416/3358272 should enable you to run an expression with a maximum timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way

```
library(microbenchmark)

f1 = function(t) Sys.sleep(t+rnorm(1, sd=0.01))
maxdif = 10

mb = microbenchmark(f1(.1), f1(.2), times=1)
if(abs(mb$time[1]-mb$time[2])/1000000>maxdif) {
  mb} else {microbenchmark(f1(.1), f1(.2), times=10)}
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# f1(0.1)  90.00902  98.01966 101.7992 102.9737 106.0218 112.8290    10
# f1(0.2) 188.00302 197.09390 201.1029 202.4914 205.0135 208.9931    10

mb = microbenchmark(f1(.1), f1(5), times=1)
if(abs(mb$time[1]-mb$time[2])/1000000>maxdif) {
  mb} else {microbenchmark(f1(.1), f1(5), times=10)}
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# f1(0.1)  103.021  103.021  103.021  103.021  103.021  103.021     1
# f1(5) 5010.939 5010.939 5010.939 5010.939 5010.939 5010.939     1
```

First, I check what the difference is for a single function execution, and if it is less than `maxdif` seconds, I do a comparison for 20 calls.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @r2evans' answer using`base::SetTimeLimit`:

```
library(bench)

sum_x <- function(x){
  res <- 0
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    res <- res + x[i]
  }
  res
}

x <- rnorm(1e8)
sum_x(x)
sum(x)

max_time <- 0.1

bench::mark("loop" = sum_x(x),
            "loop_capped" = tryCatch(expr = {setTimeLimit(max_time); sum_x(x)}, error = function(x){return(NA)}),
            "base" = sum(x), 
            iterations = 10, 
            check = FALSE)

# # A tibble: 3 x 13
# expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
# <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#   1 loop           2.95s    4.48s     0.231        0B        0    10     0     43.38s
# 2 loop_capped 102.72ms 110.53ms     9.19         0B        0    10     0      1.09s
# 3 base        124.78ms 142.31ms     6.89         0B        0    10     0      1.45s
# # ... with 4 more variables: result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

Note that I set the runtime to 0.1s, and `tryCatch` and `SetTimeLimit` add a little overhead (which will not matter when the computation takes much longer than 0.1s).