# Is there a way to timeout a MySql query when using DBI and dbGetQuery?

Tags: mysql, r, jdbc, timeout, r-dbi

I realize that

`dbGetQuery comes with a default implementation that calls dbSendQuery, then dbFetch, ensuring that the result is always freed by dbClearResult.`

and

`dbClearResult frees all resources (local and remote) associated with a result set. In some cases (e.g., very large result sets) this can be a critical step to avoid exhausting resources (memory, file descriptors, etc.)`

But my team just experienced a locked table that we went into MySQL to `kill pid` and I'm wondering - is there a way to timeout a query submitted using the `DBI` package?

I'm looking for and can't find the equivalent of

`dbGetQuery(conn = connection, 'select stuff from that_table', timeout = 90)`

I tried this, and profiled the function with and without the parameter set and it doesn't appear it does anything; why would it, if `dbClearResult` is always in play?

Comment: There's a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891073/time-out-an-r-command-via-something-like-try .  General idea is to fork the command and use a `Sys.time()` in the main thread followed by `tools::pskill()` if it takes too long.

Comment: Which Engine are you using (MyISAM or InnoDB)?  Does the connector wait for the entire resultset?  Or does it provide the data incrementally?  This choice, if possible, has a direct impact on your question.

Comment: d8aninja did the information provided help address your problem? I am just checking I understood your question correctly.

Comment: yes you did! @Technophobe01

Comment: Oh, great. Always happy to help - just checking. Take care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, my sense is you need to rely on your MySQL server to implement your required query timeout. Why? `dbQuery` is sending a client request to the server you want the server to run the query and timeout.

#### Proposed Solution:

Include a statement execution hint in the query you submit to your MySQL database.

**nb.** The query data returned may be too large for you to consume but that is a different problem.

### MySql Example:

The **MAX_EXECUTION_TIME** hint is permitted only for **SELECT** statements. It places a limit N (a timeout value in milliseconds) on how long an SQL statement is permitted to execute before the server terminates it.

---

```
MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(N)
```

Example with a timeout of 1 second (1000 milliseconds):

```
SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000) */ * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 WHERE ...
```

The **MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(N)** hint sets a statement execution timeout of N milliseconds. If this option is absent or N is 0, the statement timeout established by the max_execution_time system variable applies.

The **MAX_EXECUTION_TIME** hint is applicable as follows:

For statements with multiple **SELECT** keywords, such as unions or statements with subqueries, **MAX_EXECUTION_TIME** applies to the entire statement and must appear after the first **SELECT**.

It applies to read-only **SELECT** statements. Statements that are not read-only are those that invoke a stored function that modifies data as a side effect.

It does not apply to **SELECT** statements in stored programs and is ignored.

---

I hope the above approach helps move you in the right direction.