# R - plumber, how to add a stop/quit condition to the run?

Tags: r, plumber

I have a small API, that I need to stop running if a certain time in the day is reached, say midnight for example, and then continue on to the rest of the program. And that independant from a call from a request. Beacause one could include a function that breaks the process by checking the Sy.time(), but that will only be executed if a request come through.
My guess is that I have to modify some attribute of the $run, but can't find much about it on the internet.
I know that one could get the pid and kill it with a system command, but I don't know if that solution makes sure that the rest of the program runs.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

The file containing the function looks like :
(my_file.R)

```
#* @param x My argument
#* @get /lag_lead 
function(x){
 x <- as.numeric(x)  
 c(x-1, x+1) 
}
```

and the running script :

```
library(plumber)
mon_api <- plumb('my_file.R')
mon_api$run(port = 8000)
print('hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so, would be to set a timeout with `withTimeout` which is a wrapper for `setTimeLimit`

```
library(R-utils)
withTimeout(mon_api$run(port = 8000), timeout = 30)
# timeout is in seconds

# calculate timeout, using difftime between now and midnight
tmo <- as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct("2018-12-28 00:00:00"), Sys.time(), units = "secs"))
withTimeout(mon_api$run(port = 8000), timeout = tmo)
```

Some other timeout solutions, one using `parallel`
[Time out an R command via something like try()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891073/time-out-an-r-command-via-something-like-try)

Comment: Hello and thanks alot, this is what I was lookibg for, but the library is not available at the R server I use ! I will try to mimick the function. Thanks again