# How to stop a script from running after certain length of data in R?

Tags: r, iteration

I have a timeseries data and I want to run the code for 1 year and break before iterating the process for next year. Can anyone help me with this?
So far my code looks like this.

```
LR= 0.004    #Mean lapse rate 
L_Tmean = array(dim=c(length(Met_data), length(elevation_bands)))
for (i in 1:length(elevation_bands)){
  if (length(Met_data) > 366){ break}
  else{ L_Tmean[,i] = Met_data$Temp- LR*(elevation_bands[i]-Jasper_elevation)
  print(i)

  }

}
```

This is not providing me what I want. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please provide `elevation_bands`!

Comment: [`R.utils::withTimeout`](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/R.utils/blob/develop/R/withTimeout.R) exists. @landau provided a much-reduced version in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53018594 that works in base R (no other packages) and is much easier to read, imo.

Comment: Why not split the data by year, use apply-family functions and then combine?