# Telling a loop to "Skip" an iteration if it takes too long

Tags: r

I have this code in R:

```
output = list()

for (i in 1:999)

    {tryCatch({
        {
            link_i <- paste0(www.some_website, i+1,  /some_extension/, i,  .com)

            material_i <- fromJSON(link_i)

            output[[i]] <- material_i
        }

    }, error = function(e){})
}
```

Due to the nature of the code I am running, I have noticed that sometimes this loop gets "stuck" on a specific iteration. For instance, this loop might get stuck on the 45th iteration and take a very long time.

I am looking for some mechanism to tell the computer that "if more than x seconds is spent on a certain iteration, skip to the next iteration".

I found this function over here that might be useful: *[withTimeout: Evaluate an R expression and interrupts it if it takes too long](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/2.11.0/topics/withTimeout)*, but I am not sure if this is the correct function to use for such a task.

What can be recommended and how can I to use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time out an R command via something like try()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891073/time-out-an-r-command-via-something-like-try)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you linked to seems quite appropriate to me (but I've never used it). Here's an example with a function `foo()` that is quite fast for all inputs except when `x = 5` where it takes 5 seconds to run.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(R.utils))

# function that is fast except when x = 5
foo <- function(x) {
  if (x == 5) {
    Sys.sleep(5)
  } else {
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
  }
  return(x)
}

# create a list to store the results
res <- vector("list", length = 10L)

# Make a loop where we try to store the result of each iteration. If iteration
# takes more than 1 sec, then skip it.
for (i in 1:10) {
  print(i)
  tryCatch({
    res[[i]] <- withTimeout({
      foo(i)
    }, timeout = 1)
  }, TimeoutException = function(ex) {
    message("Timeout. Skipping.")
    res[[i]] <- NULL
  })
}
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 4
#> [1] 5
#> Timeout. Skipping.
#> [1] 6
#> [1] 7
#> [1] 8
#> [1] 9
#> [1] 10

res
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 7
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 8
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 9
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] 10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @ bretauv: thank you so much! just to clarify:  to use this code, all I need to do is insert my R code in the middle of "withTimeout({
    }"? Thank you so much!

Comment: yes, replace `foo(i)` by your code